# Swift: Unable to cast function pointer to (void*) for use in C-style third party library

Tags: c, swift, function, pointers, casting

**How do I cast a function pointer in Swift to a (void*) for use in a third party C-style library?**

I am programming an acquisition card that requires setting up an interrupt callback using a C-style function provided by a third party library. That particular function, which must be called to set up the callback, takes a (void*) argument for the callback. In C, this works:

```
// somefile.c
int PHX_StreamRead( tHandle, etAcq, void*);

PHX_StreamRead(handle, PHX_START, (void*)&phxvptrs_callback);

static void phxvptrs_callback(tHandle h, ui32 mask, void *p) {
     //... stuff
}
```

But in Swift, I am unable to call PHX_StreamRead() using the function pointer phxvptrs_callback, because I get a compilation error (wrong pointer type):

```
// file.swift

PHX_StreamRead(handle, PHX_START, &phxvptrs_callback) // Does not compile
// Error: "Cannot pass immutable value as inout argument: phxvptrs_callback is a function"
```

However, (surprisingly to me at least), all my attempts to cast that pointer to anything that looks like an UnsafeRawPointer failed:

```
// attempts.swift

typealias callbackFctType = ((tHandle, ui32, UnsafeMutableRawPointer) -> Void)

let p1 = UnsafeRawPointer(&phxvptrs_callback) // does not compile
// Error: "Cannot pass immutable value as inout argument: phxvptrs_callback is a function"

let p2 = UnsafePointer<callbackFctType>(&phxvptrs_callback) // Similar error
```

I figured out a workaround (below) but **I would like to understand why these casts are refusing to compile**. I assumed pretty much anything could be cast to UnsafeRawPointer.

My workaround has been to create a small C file with the callback definition and a wrapper function MyPHX_StreamRead_START_WithCallBack() that just calls PHX_StreamRead() with the proper accepted C syntax:

```
// file.c
static void phxvptrs_callback(tHandle h, ui32 mask, void *p) {
     //... stuff
}

int MyPHX_StreamRead_START_WithCallBack(tHandle handle) {
    return PHX_StreamRead(handle, PHX_START, &phxvptrs_callback);
}
```

Of course, calling that wrapper from Swift is not an issue and solves my problem but I find this solution "Unswift".

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, the only way to convert function pointer types in Swift is using `unsafeBitCast`.

Try something like this:

```
PHX_StreamRead(handle, PHX_START, unsafeBitCast(phxvptrs_callback, to: UnsafeMutableRawPointer.self))
```

---

#### EDIT

If you get "fatal error: can't unsafeBitCast between types of different sizes", Swift may not be treating `phxvptrs_callback` as a C-function (`@convention(c)` closure). In such cases, a little more code needed:

```
typealias callbackFctType = @convention(c) (tHandle, ui32, UnsafeMutableRawPointer?)->Void

let callbackWrapper: callbackFctType = phxvptrs_callback

PHX_StreamRead(handle, PHX_START, unsafeBitCast(callbackWrapper, to: UnsafeMutableRawPointer.self))
```

or this would compile and work as expected:

```
typealias callbackFctType = @convention(c) (tHandle, ui32, UnsafeMutableRawPointer?)->Void

PHX_StreamRead(handle, PHX_START, unsafeBitCast(phxvptrs_callback as callbackFctType, to: UnsafeMutableRawPointer.self))
```

---

#### EDIT2

To write a callback in Swift, you can write something like this:

```
typealias callbackFctType = @convention(c) (tHandle, ui32, UnsafeMutableRawPointer?)->Void

let myCallback: callbackFctType = {handle, mask, p in
    //This closure cannot capture the context of its surrounding scope.
    //(Which means this closure cannot use `self` even when in a class.)
    //...
}

PHX_StreamRead(handle, PHX_START, unsafeBitCast(myCallback, to: UnsafeMutableRawPointer.self))
```

Comment: This does not seem to work, although it does compile.  I get an exception thrown when running it: "fatal error: can't unsafeBitCast between types of different sizes"

Comment: Are you really passing a C-function? Usual Swift functions cannot be converted to `UnsafeMutableRawPointer`.

Comment: @Daniel, I modified my code and could have reproduced the same error: "fatal error: can't unsafeBitCast between types of different sizes". I'll soon update my answer.

Comment: I was really hoping to define the callback in swift since I figured the functions may be defined differently but they were really the same underlying code.

Comment: @Daniel, You can write your callback in Swift in the similar way in the **EDIT** part. (I'll add another example to my answer.) Remember only _top level functions_ and _closure literals which does not capture context_ are converted to `@convention(c)` closures.